# How can I check the check that two packages are signed by the same key?

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

One of my Android applications relies on another package to be installed as a license key. I could have gone with in-app purchases but key/license is the same for many of my apps.

In order to unlock some paid functionality in my app, I check for the existence of the package  `com.example.license`. This works just fine but in order to add a an extra layer of rigidity, I would like to check that my package and the licence key package are signed by the same key be it debug or release. How can I check this? Is it as simple as calling [`PackageManager.checkSignatures`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkSignatures%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here: [Get certificate fingerprint from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293019/get-certificate-fingerprint-from-android-app/9294410#9294410) I've put some example how to get certificate from application. You just need to run this code against your app and the license package (just replace this.getPackageName with the com.example.license)