# Google Maps not working on release Android bundle

Tags: android, authentication, gradle, google-cloud-platform, fingerprint

I've seen this question a lot on Internet but nothing works for me.

I have my Android app which uses Google Maps services to display a map.

I've set up two variants: `debug` and `release`.

The **debug** variant has no signing at all, while the **release** does. I created the corresponding `my_app.jks` keystore, which is placed in my main `/app` folder.

My release variant is configured as:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

and the values are set in `release-keystore.properties` at root level.

In GCP, I generated an API KEY and restricted it to Android apps with both: debug and release fingerprint.

My release fingerprint was created following Google's documentation:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

I entered the requested password and it output the SHA-1 fingerprint. That fingerprint was the one I set on GCP with the correct package name `com.my_app`.

Then, I run the command

```
./gradlew :app:bundleGooglePlayRelease
```

to create the bundle which I manually upload to Google Play Store for Internal Testing. I downloaded the app but the map remains grey.

> For my understanding, as the bundle is signed up with the release keystore, the SHA-1 is linked to that bundle so should be enough to authenticate the API KEY.

---

Things I've tried but didn't work:

- Run the release variant in an emulator (show grey map, too)
- Hardcode the MAPS_API key is directly in project's Android Manifest to ensure the value is correct
- Creating a separate API KEY, to check there's no issue with restricting the same package name to two different fingerprints
- Try to generate the release fingerprint with wrong keystore values to ensure I have not mistyped any value

  - The build failed, so the values I've used were correct

---

**UPDATE**
Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875845/how-is-google-verifying-sha1-and-package-name-in-api-calls), I got the SHA-1 from code and printed it. It turns out, it is a different than the one I've locally obtained with the `keytool` command.

I will work on figuring out why they differ. Any help is welcome.

Comment: This is because you've signed with another key; with Play Signing, there's then even a third one.

Comment: yes, I've found out that. I tried with that SHA-1 and now it's working!! thanks.. i will answer my question with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching and, as Martin Zeitler commented, it was not authenticating the API KEY since the app is using the SHA-1 from Google App Signing

> GCP -> SetUp -> App signing

There are three fingerpints:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-256

linking that SHA-1 to the API KEY, solves the problem