# Security in Inter process communication in android using explicit intents

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc

I am developing an android app through which I wish to pass data to another app on my phone. I have been able to do this using explicit custom intent. But my issue is that I want to make this communication secure i.e. the data that i pass should be available only to that one particular application. For this i have tried using package name permission as follows in both the apps:

```
    <permission    android:name="com.example.ex1.ex2"    android:label="ex1"    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

But my concern is that using the same package name any other application could still interact with my app and get this data. My data is secure (credit card details etc) hence I want to make sure that no app can read data apart from the destination app that I specify. How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

If the second application is developed by you, then you must have it's release key signature. And if you have keystore, you know it's [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101444/6507689)

You might check if the [hash is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579239/6507689).

But be aware of the [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39348300/6507689) on Adroid version below KitKat (API 19)

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, It solves the exact problem we had.