# Generate token for access server resources

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, android-security

I am trying to generate token at run time using sign certificate and verify that token on server to access any resources. I don't want to store token in XML file because it is available after reverse engineering of APK

Code for generating token  is

```
public String getToken() {
    Signature[] sigs;
    try {
        sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        String token = sigs[0].toCharsString();
        return token;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Issue is some device return different token even apk is generated from the same certificate, don't know the reason why it is returning different token for some devices.

All i want is generate a token which could be used to access web resources, and i don't want to store token in apk no one can get the token by decompiling apk.

Comment: _some device return different token_ so you say there are some devices which give you same token?

Comment: we have added log file on server,major devices returning same token but some of them are returning different token(1% user return different token).

Comment: regid = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); get like this way

Comment: is it unique value that is generated based on sign certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store token with C or C++
and add signature verification

```
public static String getSignature(Context context) {
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
    return signatures[0].toCharsString();
} catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

```
const char * app_signature = "singsing";
static int is_valid = 0;
void
Java_com_xxx_xxx_nativeInit(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject context_object){
    jclass context_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, context_object);

    //context.getPackageManager()
    jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, context_class, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject package_manager_object = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context_object, methodId);
    if (package_manager_object == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    //context.getPackageName()
    methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, context_class, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring package_name_string = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context_object, methodId);
    if (package_name_string == NULL) {
        return ;
    }
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,context_class);

    //PackageManager.getPackageInfo(Sting, int)
    //public static final int GET_SIGNATURES= 0x00000040;
    jclass pack_manager_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, package_manager_object);
    methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, pack_manager_class, "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,pack_manager_class);
    jobject package_info_object = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, package_manager_object, methodId, package_name_string, 0x40);
    if (package_info_object == NULL) {
        return ;
    }
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,package_manager_object);

    //PackageInfo.signatures[0]
    jclass package_info_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, package_info_object);
    jfieldID fieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, package_info_class, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,package_info_class);
    jobjectArray signature_object_array = (jobjectArray)(*env)->GetObjectField(env,package_info_object, fieldId);
    if (signature_object_array == NULL) {
        return ;
    }
    jobject signature_object = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env,signature_object_array, 0);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,package_info_object);
    jclass signature_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, signature_object); 
    methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, signature_class,  "toCharsString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,signature_class);
    jstring signature_jstirng = (jstring) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, signature_object, methodId);
    const  char *sign=(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, signature_jstirng,NULL); 
    if (strcmp(sign,app_signature)==0 || strcmp(sign,app_j_s)==0) {
        is_valid= 1;
    } 
    return;
}
```

Comment: there is error can't resolve `GetObjectClass(contextObject)` ,can you please provide **.c** file

Comment: is they any way i can encrypt `c_msg` in same funtion.

Comment: thank you for update.can you please provide some tutorial,i want to generate encrypted string from app_signature.that verified on server for access the resources.

Comment: a simple example

Android-
1.get unique id from phone.
2.choose encryption rules and algorithm (eg. MD5,DES) .
3.encrypt id with 2.    

Server-
decode id with Android.2

Answer (score 1):

The signing certificate's fingerprint will be unique across all the devices. Would you please try this solution to get that fingerprint as String and use it as token.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22506133/4586742

Comment: what was the issue in my code?i have added log file some device calling web service different token.

Comment: so it's crack able,any one can generate **fingerprint**  using above logic and use that key for access resources.is they any solution for that.

Comment: t's also possible to generate fingerprint using some technique 'List<PackageInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageMana‌​ger.GET_SIGNATURES);' gives all list of installed package for (Signature s : pi.signatures) { Log.d("PackageTrackerfix", "old: " + s.toCharsString() + " " + s.hashCode()); }'  it return all certificate details that we are using in 'generateCertificate()'

Comment: Doing encryption of the fingerprint and pass encrypted value will increase the security.

Comment: i have already did,but if anyone get the fingerprint  so they can also try reverse engineering on it

Comment: Yes. 100% security is a lie. Why do you need to generate the token at client side. Why don't you consider some standard like [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) for authentication which involves short-lived (1 hour) tokens.

Comment: there is again new attach on my app,they have generated fingerprint  using above logic and replaced static fingerprint   with fingerprint that i am generating at run time  so now they are again able to access all the resources

Comment: for Oauth there is no login system,non user get register with app.so how to use Oauth?

Comment: Why do you need token if there is no user model? Btw, if you want to store a token securely, you can consider [Android keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)

Comment: attacker have removed the ads my application,there is IAP in my app if it's subscribed user they don't see any ads for normal user there are ads,but attacker remove the condition and always pass true for subscribed user condition and upload APK with new sign certificate,that's way i have generated token using sign certificate ,if it's signed by me then only user able to get the resources.

Answer (score 0):

@Om Infowave Developers,

I Suggest you to use a [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)
to generate a [KeyPair](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html) then use KeyPair to encrypt a Token, Store a token in shared preference. whenever you need a token decrypt token using KeyPair.

1. This way you get unique token every time.
2. Token is encrypted and secured.
3. KeyPair is different for every device hence more secure.

Also I just notice that you are returning zero-index based key. Their might be chances that key you are looking for present in subsequent indices. Suggest you to log all key stored in `Signature[] sigs`;

Hope this help.

Comment: @Sanday how to verify this token on server?

Comment: How are you currently verifying token on server? Use same way you are verifying token on server currently. only difference is you stored a token in shared preference on android device in encrypted format after its generates first time. After which pull token from shared preference decrypt token and send it to server. Let me know if you any other help. More than happy to help.

Comment: Another way is to send device ID and token to server, store both device id and token on server.