# How to get Keystore fingerprint from code

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am currently struggling with getting some security to the Unity3d app I'm working on, and I want to add verification that apk file wasn't tampered with by some patchers. I know how to get keystore fingerprint from a built app (like keytool), but I have a hard time figuring out how to get that fingerprint from the code of my app during runtime to check that it is the same. I've gone through a lot of other threads to no success so far (like this: [Get certificate fingerprint from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293019/get-certificate-fingerprint-from-android-app))

Has anyone found solution how to do this or hint where I should start looking? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the `getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint` function from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293019/get-certificate-fingerprint-from-android-app) you linked to take Android `Context` as parameter. Get the `Context` from Unity and send it to this function then mark as `static`.

**Java:**

```
public final class CertificateSHA1Fingerprint 
{

  private static String getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint(Context mContext) 
  {
  PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
  String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
  int flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
  try {
   packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags);
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
  byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();
  InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);
  CertificateFactory cf = null;
  try {
   cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
  } catch (CertificateException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  X509Certificate c = null;
  try {
   c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
  } catch (CertificateException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  String hexString = null;
  try {
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
   byte[] publicKey = md.digest(c.getEncoded());
   hexString = byte2HexFormatted(publicKey);
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return hexString;
 }

 public static String byte2HexFormatted(byte[] arr) 
 {
   StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(arr.length * 2);
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
   {
   String h = Integer.toHexString(arr[i]);
   int l = h.length();
   if (l == 1) h = "0" + h;
   if (l > 2) h = h.substring(l - 2, l);
   str.append(h.toUpperCase());
   if (i < (arr.length - 1)) str.append(':');
   }
  return str.toString();
 }
}
```

**C#**:

```
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
AndroidJavaObject unityContext;
AndroidJavaClass customClass;

public string getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint()
{
    //Replace with your full package name
    string packageName = "com.example.CertificateSHA1Fingerprint";

    unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass(packageName);

    string result = customClass.CallStatic<string>("getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint", unityContext);
    return result;
}
```

You only have to build the Java function with Android Studio and convert it into Jar or .AAR file then put it in your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder. The C# code will be able to communicate with it.

Comment: This worked like a charm, just needed to wrap my brains around how to build aar/jar files in Android Studio. Great manual! Thank you!

Comment: I did not test it but it should. Glad I was able to help. Building .aar and .jar is hard for new users but you will get used to that once you do it once.  You are welcome!