# What are the security implacations of uplaoding SHA256 thumbprint to /.well-known/assetlinks.json

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

Are there any security implications for exposing this thumbprint? Will it compromise my signing key?

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa#remove_the_url_bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no security implications from adding the SHA-256 Fingerprint the `assetstatements.json` file.

In fact the Fingerprint is already available as part of any signed APK, and it can be viewed with the following command:

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk
```

It also possible for one Android app to view the Fingerprint from another app, using an approach similar to the described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293019/get-certificate-fingerprint-from-android-app).